# ways to change annotation 'meta.helm.sh/release-name'

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am using helm to deploy a **namespace** resource but each time helm adds annotations automatically:

```
meta.helm.sh/release-name=my-pr-111
```

which creates troubles for subsequent helm deployments using the same namespace

For example, I first deployed the namespace using command:

```
helm upgrade my-pr-111 ./path/helm/chart --install --atomic
```

Then the namespace is deployed with annotations:

```
meta.helm.sh/release-name=my-pr-111
```

Then if I do another deployment for the same namespace using command:

```
helm upgrade my-pr-222 ./path/helm/chart --install --atomic
```

Then I got an error:

Unable to continue with install: Namespace "my-space" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "my-pr-222": current value is "my-pr-111"

Anyone knows how to handle this situation?

Comment: Do you actually need to include the Namespace resource in your chart?  Can you create the Namespace outside of Helm; and then pass a `--namespace` option in so that Helm stores its state in the relevant namespace?  Can you install each PR build in its own namespace so there isn't a conflict?

Comment: Due to our current CI/CD setup, I can't create multiple namespaces which will pollute our namespaces. Also we have other shared resources across helm releases. Just want to check whether it is feasible for helm.

Comment: IMHO Helm should **not** add any annotation/label by itself. They could simply provide a template macro that adds them on explicit request by the user...Or let the user use their own annotations/labels